# How to load the warmup state of couchbase in JAVA

Tags: java, database, statistics, command-line-interface, couchbase

I'm a 2st year junior web developer.
As shown in the attached picture, *I would like to check the [**N node warmup**] **status** (yellow status) in the couchbase UI **in java or through the cbstats CLI**.*
Can you please tell me how?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I asked, but I found the answer myself. It is a method using command as cbstats. I will write down an example below.

```
./cbstats -b [bucketname] -p [password] 127.0.0.1:11210 all | grep ep_degraded_mode
```

If you know how to use api in JAVA other than the above method, please let me know.